# Having some trouble connecting an android app to an online database

Tags: java, android

I have been running into some issues with a small Android project for school. I need to request a password from an online database via a .php by sending it the username. It should return an encrypted password. But there seems to be something wrong with the method I use to connect to the database and receive the password. LogCat gives me these:

Error in HTTP connection java.net.UnknownHostException: boekenapp.atwebpages.com
Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: end of input at character 0 of

So my question: What did I do wrong?/What do I need to change to make it work?

The code:

```
public static String phpconnect(String name, String value) {
        String result = "";
        InputStream is = null;

        //variables to send to database
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name,value));

        //HTTP post
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI connection = new URI("http://boekenapp.atwebpages.com/phpscript.php");
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(connection);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in HTTP connection "+e.toString());
        } 

        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();

            result=sb.toString();
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        //parse JSON data
        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("log_tag","userid: "+json_data.getInt("userid")+", password: "+json_data.getString("password"));
            }
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The second try block will always execute, as you only log in the first catch block.

You should consider a return statement or a throw statement. An alternative is to embed the second try block inside the first one, but that's less readable maybe.

In your case, the problem is that the connection itself fails. Are you sure you have network up ? Can you ping the host from your computer and from Android (you can use `adb shell ping <host>` on CLI).

And don't truncate the error stacks on their first line, a stack has to be read fully, top-down until you find your piece of code that is causing the bug.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the URL from this code used in a browser redirects to www.alotspace.com/error-404/ Just so you know.

Without testing, just looking at the code, I would start with checking the status line of the response. This is how

```
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
if (statusCode == 200) {
    // here all is OK, you can check for 404 and so on
}
```

Also I see you handling the response with a buffered reader putting everything in a StringBuilder further in code. A better alternative would be using [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

But focus on the initial network related exception first. The other exceptions are just a result of the separate try/catch blocks (as @Snicolas pointed out already). Unknownhost sounds like no network. Being redirect would just return different output than expected, not unkownhost. To verify that browse to the url from your android device you're testing on.